# What new moves, if any, have been introduced in Gen 6?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Are there any new moves which did not exist before generation 6?

Comment: Diagonal​​​​​​​

Comment: New Fairy TMs as well (eg Fairy Wind)

Comment: This is going to be a huge long list possibly.  I don't know for sure, but it could be quite a long list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/xy/attacks.shtml), the list is rather long.

### Physical

- Fairy [Play Rough](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/playrough.shtml)
- Electric [Nuzzle](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/nuzzle.shtml)
- Bug [Fell Stinger](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/fellstinger.shtml)
- Bug [Sticky Web](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/stickyweb.shtml)
- Fight [Flying Press](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/flyingpress.shtml)
- Fight [Power-Up Punch](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/power-uppunch.shtml)
- Grass [Petal Blizzard](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/petalblizzard.shtml)
- Ground [Land's Wrath](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/land%27swrath.shtml)
- Ghost [Phantom Force](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/phantomforce.shtml)
- Water [Water Shuriken](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/watershuriken.shtml)

### Special

- Fairy [Dazzling Gleam](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/dazzlinggleam.shtml)
- Fairy [Disarming Voice](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/disarmingvoice.shtml)
- Fairy [Draining Kiss](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/drainingkiss.shtml)
- Fairy [Fairy Wind](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/fairywind.shtml)
- Fairy [Moonblast](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/moonblast.shtml)
- Normal [Boomburst](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/boomburst.shtml)
- Electric [Parabolic Charge](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/paraboliccharge.shtml)
- Bug [Infestation](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/infestation.shtml)
- Ice [Freeze-Dry](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/freeze-dry.shtml)
- Fire [Mystical  Fire](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/mysticalfire.shtml)
- Flying [Oblivion Wing](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/oblivionwing.shtml)

### Status

- Fairy [Aromatic Mist](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/aromaticmist.shtml)
- Fairy [Baby-Doll Eyes](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/baby-dolleyes.shtml)
- Fairy [Crafty Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/craftyshield.shtml)
- Fairy [Fairy Lock](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/fairylock.shtml)
- Fairy [Flower Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/flowershield.shtml)
- Fairy [Geomancy](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/geomancy.shtml)
- Fairy [Misty Terrain](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/mistyterrain.shtml)
- Normal [Confide](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/confide.shtml)
- Normal [Noble Roar](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/nobleroar.shtml)
- Normal [Play Nice](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/playnice.shtml)
- Electric [Eerie Impulse](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/eerieimpulse.shtml)
- Electric [Electric Terrain](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/electricterrain.shtml)
- Electric [Electrify](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/electrify.shtml)
- Electric [Ion Deluge](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/iondeluge.shtml)
- Electric [Magnetic Flux](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/magneticflux.shtml)
- Bug [Powder](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/powder.shtml)
- Fight [Mat Block](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/matblock.shtml)
- Grass [Forest's Curse](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/forest%27scurse.shtml)
- Grass [Grassy Terrain](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/grassyterrain.shtml)
- Grass [Spiky Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/spikyshield.shtml)
- Steel [King's Shield](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/king%27sshield.shtml)
- Dark [Parting Shot](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/partingshot.shtml)
- Dark [Topsy-Turvy](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/topsy-turvy.shtml)
- Poison [Venom Drench](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/venomdrench.shtml)

In addition to that, a variety of moves have also been [updated](http://www.serebii.net/xy/updatedattacks.shtml).

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect it to be that many.